# Apply test (Jarque-Bera) to subgroups with map()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I'm trying to run a test (Jarque-Bera) on subgroups of my dataset. I'm trying to use `purrr`s function `map()` for this, but somehow it fails for me.

For the example here, I'll use the built-in `ChickWeight`dataset:

Load some packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tseries)
```

The data looks like this:

```
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(weight, fill = Diet)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~Diet)
```

[image]

I'm now trying to use the Jarque-Bera test on the subgroups Diet 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I know how to use it on one of the groups like this:

```
ChickWeight %>% 
  filter(Diet == 1) %>% 
  pull(weight) %>% 
  jarque.bera.test()
```

Which returns:

```
    Jarque Bera Test

data:  .
X-squared = 46.687, df = 2, p-value = 7.278e-11
```

But now, I would like to do this for all subgroups. So I nest the data like this:

```
nst <- ChickWeight %>% 
  nest(-Diet)
```

Now I thought I could immediately apply `purrr`s `map()` function, but some how it fails:

```
tsts <- nst %>% 
  map(jb = map(data, jarque.bera.test(weight)))
```

Which returns:

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

I also tried:

```
tsts <- nst %>% 
  mutate(jb = map(data, jarque.bera.test(weight)))
```

And that yields:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
> Evaluation error: object 'weight' not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `nst` is a data frame; under the hood a data frame is a list of columns. So if you apply `map` to `nst`, it will map over the columns instead of mapping over the groups in your data. Also, note that the second argument to `map` must be a function (or a few other kinds of expressions that are shorthand for functions---see the documentation for `purrr::map`).

There are many ways you could solve your problem. My favorite would be to use `group_by` and `do` from **dplyr** along with `tidy` from **broom**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tseries)
library(broom)

ChickWeight %>%
    group_by(Diet) %>%
    do(tidy(jarque.bera.test(.$weight)))
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# # Groups:   Diet [4]
#   Diet  statistic  p.value parameter method          
#   <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>           
# 1 1         46.7  7.28e-11         2 Jarque Bera Test
# 2 2         18.8  8.36e- 5         2 Jarque Bera Test
# 3 3         12.4  2.00e- 3         2 Jarque Bera Test
# 4 4          5.17 7.54e- 2         2 Jarque Bera Test
```

Note that `tidy` takes the output of `jarque.bera.test` and turns it into a one-row data frame, and this is repeated for each group by the `do` function. Here's a pure **dplyr** approach:

```
ChickWeight %>%
    group_by(Diet) %>%
    summarize(p.value = jarque.bera.test(weight)$p.value)
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   Diet   p.value
#   <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 1     7.28e-11
# 2 2     8.36e- 5
# 3 3     2.00e- 3
# 4 4     7.54e- 2
```

Next is an approach that uses `nest` and `map`. Note that the second column of the data frame created by `nest` is a list-column. We use `pull` to pull just the list-column and then use `map` to perform the Jarque-Bera test on each group.

```
ChickWeight %>%
    nest(-Diet) %>%
    pull(data) %>%
    map(~ jarque.bera.test(.$weight))
# [[1]]
# 
#   Jarque Bera Test
# 
# data:  .$weight
# X-squared = 46.687, df = 2, p-value = 7.278e-11
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
#   Jarque Bera Test
# 
# data:  .$weight
# X-squared = 18.779, df = 2, p-value = 8.36e-05
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# 
#   Jarque Bera Test
# 
# data:  .$weight
# X-squared = 12.426, df = 2, p-value = 0.002003
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# 
#   Jarque Bera Test
# 
# data:  .$weight
# X-squared = 5.1686, df = 2, p-value = 0.07545
```

Note that map accepts a formula as a compact way of writing an [anonymous function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions). Finally, here's a couple somewhat clunkier approaches that combine `map` and **dplyr**:

```
map(1:4, ~ filter(ChickWeight, Diet == .) %>% pull(weight) %>% jarque.bera.test)

map(1:4, ~ filter(ChickWeight, Diet == .)) %>%
    map(~ pull(., weight)) %>%
    map(~ jarque.bera.test(.))
```